# Autofocus on input in React without making the placeholder disappear until key event

Tags: jquery, html, reactjs

I'm trying to autofocus the cursor on the input when the page loads, which I'm doing with:

```
<input placeholder="Enter text here" autoFocus={true} />
```

However, when I do this, the placeholder disappears. I want to have the placeholder show until the user is ready to start typing, and only on a key event, disappear. How would you do this in React, or does it require extra js/css to make work?

Comment: I am [not seeing this behavior](http://codepen.io/tyrsius/pen/QjoROd) in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Tyrsius You're right, forgot I have the following code below- removing that did it. This works as expected in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that I had the following inside my stylesheet:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

Removing that fixes the issue.

Comment: That's honestly hilarious =)